# Setting timeoutInterval to unlimited

Tags: ios, swift

I don't really want a timeoutInterval so cache will always be available when offline, but I can't leave it out either. Is there a way to set it to unlimited?

```
var requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple

```
var requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
```

Comment: It's really this simple? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah it accepts variable time Double, double can return infinity so its infinite interval

Comment: Sure, I was just waiting till I was able to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

var requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)